# Trying to sum numbers between numbers more efficiently

Tags: python

TLDR: Need to make code below more efficient.

I'm trying to solve a coding challenge that requires I sum all numbers between two numbers. My code shown below is passing the tests but is taking too long to run, causing me to fail due to a time out.

Is there any way to rewrite this to do the same thing in less time?

EDIT: solved, thank you so much for your solutions

```
def get_sum(a,b):
    res = 0
    if b>a:
        for i in range(a,b):
            res = sum(range(a,b+1))
            return res
    if a > b: 
        for i in range (b,a):
            res = sum(range(b,a+1))
        return res
    elif a == b:
        return a
```

Comment: you could use some algebra, instead of a raw sum

Comment: solve it analytically: ```S=(b-a+1)*(b+a)/2```

Comment: Why are you using a loop at all? `sum(...)` already iterates over the entire range itself, and the `return` statement ensures the loop (and the function itself) exists after the first iteration. (Separate from the fact that brute-force addition is what takes too long, anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
def get_sum2(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return a
    return sum([n for n in range(a, b+1)] if b > a else [n for n in range(b, a+1)])

if __name__=="__main__":
    print(get_sum2(1, 3))
```

Answer (score 3):

a little math won't harm.

[image]

so this should work.

```py
def get_sum(a,b):
    return (b-a+1)*(a+b)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion, when you find yourself trying to check for the order of parameters do something like this so you don't have to write the same code twice:

```py
if a>b:
  a,b = b,a

# your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Using the formula for the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):

```py
def get_sum(a,b):
    if a > b:
        b, a = a, b
    sum_from_1_to_a = a * (a + 1) / 2
    sum_from_1_to_b = b * (b + 1) / 2
    return sum_from_1_to_b - sum_from_1_to_a
```

You can simplify this, obviously, but I left it this way so it is obvious how the formula is being applied.

Also, are you sure if `a == b` you should return `a`? Aren't there 0 numbers between them if they have the same value?

Comment: if the goal is to sum all numbers between all and `a` and `b` are among them you should return `a`

Comment: @zooid then in that case I guess you would just add `a -= 1` before you do any calculations.

Comment: Why would it be like that? Imagine this `sum([a])`. The result is the value of `a`